# Reading serial data from an Arduino using C++

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino

So that's what I want to do. I already have some functions, for example this one to write data to the serial port, which works perfectly:

```
bool WriteData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar)
{
    DWORD bytesSend;

    //Try to write the buffer on the Serial port
    if(!WriteFile(hSerial, (void *)buffer, nbChar, &bytesSend, 0))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

The reading function is like this:

```
int ReadData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar)
{
//Number of bytes we'll have read
DWORD bytesRead;
//Number of bytes we'll really ask to read
unsigned int toRead;

ClearCommError(hSerial, NULL, &status);
//Check if there is something to read
if(status.cbInQue>0)
{
    //If there is we check if there is enough data to read the required number
    //of characters, if not we'll read only the available characters to prevent
    //locking of the application.
    if(status.cbInQue>nbChar)
    {
        toRead = nbChar;
    }
    else
    {
        toRead = status.cbInQue;
    }

    //Try to read the require number of chars, and return the number of read bytes on success
    if(ReadFile(hSerial, buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL) && bytesRead != 0)
    {
        return bytesRead;
    }

}

//If nothing has been read, or that an error was detected return -1
return -1;

}
```

And no matter what I do with the arduino, this function always returns -1, I even tried loading a code that constantly writes a character to the serial port, but nothing.

I got the functions from here: http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

so my functions are basically the same. I just copied them into my code instead of using them as classes objects, but more than that it's the same.

So that's my problem, I can write data to the serial but I can't read, what can I try?

Comment: What does your line look like that opens the serial port? And what's in `GetLastError`? Are you sure the device is actually giving you something to read?

Comment: @MatsPetersson hSerial = CreateFile(wText,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);

hSerial is a variable defined as HANDLE hSerial. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I don't know how to isolate where the problem is happening. The device is definitely sending data, if I open the serial monitor of the arduino IDE I can see it. The program can send data too. The problem is with reading it. The variable: status.cbInQue is 0, which should be the number of bytes to read.

Comment: You do realize, I suppose that you have ommitted the line that fetches the status in your read function, which probably means that the if-statement checking `cbInQue` is going to fail?

Comment: @MatsPetersson mmm... Ok that's weird. I don't remember at all deleting that line. I now get -1 again, but cbInQue is different from 0 (around 2000, which I guess it's the number of character arduino sends before the line is executed. The variable bytesRead ends up being 0 too.

Comment: You will need to pay attention to SetCommState().  You won't receive anything if hardware handshaking is enabled and the Arduino doesn't turn on the RTS and DTR signals.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you very much for your help. I honestly don't know what those are but I'm going to learn about them, as I'm planning to program some stuff in which I will need to know about serial communications. Anyway, I solved the problem about 1 minute ago, and it turned out it was just a matter of time between writing-reading data. I will answer this question. Thanks again for your help. BTW, if you know any good online information where I can learn all this stuff, I would really appreciate it. Thanks again and bye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I already solved it and it was a silly mistake. I programmed the Arduino so it would wait for a serial input before sending anything. The computer program writes and sends one line of code after another, and I guess a i7 is faster than the Atmel... and obviously the data takes some time.

Adding a Sleep(10); before reding the port from the computer was enough to finally read the data.

Thanks to @Matts for his help.